# How can I redirect input from file and then from terminal?

Tags: bash, redirection

How can I run a program in bash in such a way that first it receives some input from a file, and then, as the file ends, it will receive input from terminal?

Comment: And also, how can I receive first input not from a file, but from a constant, like this: `somecommand <<< "someinput"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ```
   cat myfile - | program
   ```

   or

   ```
   cat myfile /dev/stdin | program
   ```
2. Use `echo`, which has the same end result:

   ```
   (echo "someinput"; cat) | program
   ```